# Annoying new confirmation page in Google App Engine Launcher

Tags: macos, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-launch

After upgrading to GoogleAppEngineLauncher 1.9.18 and clicking on the Deploy button, a new tab appears in the browser with a page reading:

```
Google App Engine appcfg would like to:
* View and manage your applications deployed on Google App Engine
* View and manage your data across Google Cloud Platform services
By clicking Accept, you allow this app and Google to use your information in accordance with their respective terms of service and privacy policies. You can change this and other Account Permissions at any time.
```

So I click the Accept button and a new page appears:

```
The authentication flow has completed.
```

The deploy completes, but this happens every time I Deploy a new version.  What's up with this?  Why doesn't it remember that I accepted the TOS and Privacy Policy?  This is annoying!

Another question: How can I turn off this new "feature"?

Update: This only seems to apply to Mac launchers

Update on 2015-04-20: Upgrading to 1.9.19 has solved this problem

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted. I just upgraded the appenginelauncher and now am getting this same bit of annoyance. Can't find any documentation to help me get the previous behavior or understand why it changed. Sure would be nice if when people down-voted something they left a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you just upgrade the appenginelauncher to version 1.9.18?

Per the [release notes](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes):

> Mac Launcher now uses OAuth2 exclusively for app deployments.
>   Permissions are granted through the browser instead of a login dialog.

It looks like this is the way it is now.

Comment: Interesting detail: Mac Launcher only?

Comment: That's what the notes say. I've only used the mac launcher, so that's all I'm familiar with.